# How to bypass certain url patterns not invoking dispatcher servelet in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I declared below url pattern within servelet definition for handler mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now i have some specific url with above '/' pattern (ex: /demo/), but i dont want to allow this request to get handled by dispatcher servlet (since i dont have any handler mapping in controller for this request).

Is there any similar prototype like mvc:resources ?

It would be very thankful if someone tells how to find out whether the declared resources are invoked properly or not?
I declared like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/MainTemplate/"/>
```

In jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/components.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `interceptor` for the pattern you want and handle it there. Configure your interceptor as shown below for specific patterns. You can also exclude the url patterns you want from entering into the interceptor.

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/url_pattern/**"/>
        <exclude-mapping path="/exclude/**"/>
..
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

Comment: Great Thanks !! I will try that out.

Comment: @Dileep76 if it works choose as right answer or upvote so that it will be helpful for others